# SQL Updating two records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update two employee's data. Let say one employee's id is `1234` and the other employee's id is `5678`. Each employee has different services.

This is my table for reference

```
serv_id          emp_id      serv_name    status 
1                 1234        computer1     A
5                 1234        computer2     A
10                1234        computer3     A
37                1234        computer4     A
5                 5678        computer2     A
11                5678        projector1    A
12                5678        projector2    A
30                5678        projector3    A
37                5678        computer4     A   
35                5678        projector4    A
```

In the table above, we have 2 employees with 10 records and each employee has 5 services. What I want to do right now is to merge these two employee's services into one employee (1234) because employee 5678 is fired. However, serv_id with '5' or '37' does not need to be updated in employee 1234.

Here is my expected result. Let say A is active and I is inactive. Any suggestion on how to do it?

```
serv_id (pk)                 emp_id (fk)     serv_name    status 
1                            1234            computer1      A
5 (no update)                1234            computer2     A
10                           1234            computer3     A
11                           1234            projector1    A
12                           1234            projector2    A
30                           1234            projector3    A
35                           1234            projector4    A
37 (no update)               1234            computer4     A
11                           5678            projector1    I
37                           5678            computer4     I
5                            5678            computer2     I
11                           5678            projector1    I
12                           5678            projector2    I
30                           5678            projector3    I
37                           5678            computer4     I
35                           5678            projector4    I
```

Comment: Data in this table are corrupted, serv_id can't be primary key with duplicate values as 5 and 37. Did you provide us a correct table structure?

Comment: sorry my bad, serv_id is not pk, it is just a column. I have fixed my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
declare @tb as Table (serv_id int, emp_id int, serv_name nvarchar(20),status nvarchar(5))
insert into @tb 
select 1 ,1234,'computer1','A' union
select 5 ,1234,'computer2','A' union
select 10,1234,'computer3','A' union
select 37,1234,'computer4','A' union
select 5 ,5678,'computer2','A' union
select 11,5678,'projector1','A' union
select 12,5678,'projector2','A' union
select 30,5678,'projector3','A' union
select 37,5678,'computer4','A'  union
select 35,5678,'projector4','A'

update @tb set status ='I' where emp_id = 5678

insert into @tb select serv_id,1234,serv_name,'A' from @tb where emp_id=5678 and serv_id not in (select serv_id from @tb where emp_id=1234)

select * from @tb order by emp_id,serv_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.status='I'
FROM my_table t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN my_table t2 ON t2.serv_name=t1.serv_name AND t2.emp_id=1234   
WHERE t1.emp_id=5678
  AND t2.serv_id IS NULL
```

We can join the table to itself by `serv_name` and `emp_id` to find common `serv_name`s and then update only the records which have no same values for the emp_id=1234

Comment: Thank you for your response, I am using visual studio 2010. However, I get incorrect syntax near "LEFT"